# Is there a way to get Go to compile and link in one step (6g and 6l at once)?

Tags: bash, go

I'm trying to search Google but the keyword 'go' makes it difficult to find any useful answers.
Reading the http://golang.org/ page doesn't turn up anything useful either.

Right now, I have a simple function in my bash.rc:

```
function gogo() {
    6g -o gotmp.tmp $@;
    6l -o go.out gotmp.tmp;
    rm -f gotmp.tmp;
}
```

However, this is not perfect. It would be nice for something built in (perhaps something like gogcc but using 6g/6l backend).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have a reason to not use a build system?

There is a ready made Makefile in `$GOROOT/doc/`. Other build systems: [What build systems work with Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735993/what-build-systems-work-with-go)

Comment: Thanks. I think the Makefile should work for what I'm doing. Scons looks good, too.